# When is Hashmap or List<Hashmap> GC eligible?

Tags: java, performance, collections, garbage-collection

I have an open question since long time pertaining the hashmap GC. Checked google and other blogs , don't seem to find answers.

Here is it,

Say I have two methods one returning Hashmap and another List as below,

```
public void returnData(){
    Map<String,String> outerMap = getMap();
    for(elements from getMap){
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
    List<Map<String,Object> outerList = getListMap();
    for(elements from getListMap){
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
private Map<String,String> getMap(){
    Map<String,String> innerMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(i){
        innerMap.put("one"+i,"test"+i);
    }
    return innerMap;
}
private List<Map<String,Object>> getListMap(){
    List<Map<String,Object>> innerList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>;
    for(5 times){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("two"+i,new Object());
        innerList.add(map);
    }
    return innerList;
}
```

Per the above code please let me know,
1. When will the innerMap and innerList be eligible for GC?
2. When will the outerMap and outerList be eligible for GC?
3. Will making innerMap and innerList to null make it eligible for GC?
4. What should be done to make the outerMap and outerList eligible for GC?
5. Lastly, how to measure if GC is taken place and has cleared my unused objects? Anyways to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists and maps are like any other objects. They become eligible to GC as soon as there is no strong reference path from any GC root (static variable of thread stack).

In this case, as soon as `returnData()` stops executing, nobody has a reference leading to any of the lists and maps involved in the code, so everything becomes eligible to GC (unless of course the code hidden behind the comment stores a reference somewhere).

If you really stick to the specs, the Map referenced by outerMap becomes eligible to GC right after the first for loop.

BTW, re-reading your question, it seems that you confuse references to objects with objects. `innerMap` and `outerMap` are two references to a single object: a Map. Objects are Garbage collected. Not references.

Comment: Thanks, the code inside the comments actually converts the map/list to an JSON object using GSON API. and then the json object is returned to the UI part. That said, the moment the data is returned to UI this will be eligible for GC? please confirm!

Comment: *as soon as returnData() stops executing, nobody has a reference leading to any of the lists and maps involved in the code, so everything becomes eligible to GC*.